# How to keep the state using history.replaceState?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use the window.history.replaceState method just to show the URL shown in the browser.

```
window.history.replaceState("","","newurl.php");
```

Well, this works well and changes the URL. But what is this "State" that I set to "" here? And how should I change my code if I simply want to be the State as before? (As I said... I just wanted to change the URL and this works well, not to change the state...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replaceState()` is a way to associate some data (*any* data that can be [structured cloned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)) with the current location - without reloading the page. There's also `pushState`, that does the same thing, but you can also use the browser's back button to go back to the previous displayed url / state.

If you don't use these for something else, you don't have to care about the state you set (it's only visible to your website).

If you, on the other hand, do use states and don't want to change it, you can set it to the same state as it was before. You can get the current state with `history.state`:

```
window.history.replaceState(window.history.state, "", "newurl.php");
```

Comment: "*any* data" -> "*any [structured cloneable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)* data"

Comment: @Kaiido Well, yes, by *any*, I meant *arbitrary*.

Comment: "arbitrary"? Not sure what that means in this context. My point is that you can't pass any JS object, a Function would throw, a DOMElement would throw etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. BTW: I had some bug and thought the "state" would cause it, but now I found some other problem and fixed it.

Comment: @Kaiido Seems like I don't know the right word - I meant that it doesn't have any effect on the site, you can use it in your program for whatever you want (the number of puppies in the picture, the name of the user, an array of cars' colors, etc.). Btw, I edited it to include "structured clonability".